# If $C$ is compact in $X$, is $C \cap A$ compact in $A$ (with $A \subset X$, and the relative topology)?

Tags: general-topology

If $C$ is compact in $(X,T)$, is $C\cap A$ compact in $A$ (with $A$ contained in $X$, and $A$ endowed with the relative topology)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the real line with the usual topology; consider $C=[0,2]$ and $A=(0,1)$.

Then $C\cap A=(0,1)$. Is it compact?

If you add that $A$ is closed, then the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if $C\supseteq A$, then $C\cap A=A$. Is every subset of a compact set also compact?